# Prevent android battery managers from stopping my application service

Tags: android, service, batterymanager

`Huawei`, `Asus` and some manufacturers have system `battery manager` that prevent services to `keep running` when related application closed.

I realized that when i change my application package name to `com.telegram.messenger` battery managers (of huawei and asus) don't stop service when my application closed (service restarted after closing).

In other words when my application package name is `com.telegram.messenger` after installing application, android battery manager added my application to their list to prevent stop service when application closed but when i set my real package name It does not happen.

do `huawei`, `asus` or other manufacturers have a list included package name of famous applications like `telegram` and `whatsapp` and don't stop their services by their battery managers?

Comment: yes, big companies have deals with smartphone manufacturers to exclude their apps from annoying mechanisms like this